# ¿A qué se refiere la sentencia x for x in y if x['propiedad'] == variable en Python?

Tags: python

¿Alguien me podría explicar el proceso que lleva a cabo la siguiente línea de código? (ver la imagen para más detalles).

En concreto esta:

```
langs = [language for language in languages if language['name'] == name]
```

Ya probé el código y sé el resultado que arroja, pero aún así no entiendo la línea de código en sí, porque no soy muy influyente en Python aún. Me imagino que es un ciclo con una condicional.

Por ello, me gustaría que me explicaran qué es lo que hace paso a paso y también por qué se escribe así la sentencia en especial la parte de `language for language`, eso sí que no sé nada del porqué está allí.

[image: Bloque de código]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La siguiente línea de código es una forma resumida de recorrer, evaluar condiciones y cargar una lista

```
>>> langs = [language for language in languages if language['name'] == name]
```

**Analicemos la línea**

1. `langs = []`: esto es una declaración de lista
2. `language for language in languages if language['name'] == name` dentro del corchete o inicialización de la variable se recorre la lista `languages` que contiene varios diccionarios, se filtran aquellos que cumplen la condición `if language['name'] == name]` y finalmente se asignan a la lista `langs`

`language for language`: para entender esta parte en concreto de la línea debemos analizar de vuelta todo lo que está dentro de la asignación.

Si quitamos `language` la línea quedaría de la siguiente manera: `for language in languages if language['name'] == name` que de otra forma sería:

```
 for language in languages:
     if language['name'] == name:
```

Entonces `language` la porción que quitamos equivaldría a:

```
langs.append(language)
```

De manera que toda la línea de código en cuestión es equivalente al siguiente bloque de código:

```
>>> langs = []
>>> for language in languages:
        if language['name'] == name:
            langs.append(language)
```

**Resultado:**
Suponiendo que el valor de la variable `name == 'Python'`

```
>>> print(langs) 
[{'name': 'Python'}]
>>>
```

El resultado es lo mismo, pero el rendimiento puede ser diferente. Generalmente es más eficiente el código de la forma resumida.

Answer (score 2):

```
langs = [language for language in languages if language['name'] == name]
```

Esto es un ejemplo bastante simple de una técnica de Python y de varios otros lenguajes llamada ["list comprehension"](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) ("comprensión de listas" en castellano) y sirve para filtrar y transformar cualquier "iterable", es decir datos que pueden ser recorridos, como listas, tuplas, diccionarios solo por nombrar los básicos. Su sintaxis se podría explicar como:

```
[expresión de salida] [ciclo] [filtro]
```

El `[filtro]`puede ser opcional, la `[expresión de salida]` puede ser un elemento, varios o una transformación. En la red vas a encontrar enorme cantidad de ejemplos, a modo de muestra veamos estos casos:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
# obtengo lo número pares
print([e for e in lista if e % 2 == 0])
[2, 4, 6, 8]

# obtengo el cuadrado de cada elemento
print([e*e for e in lista])
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

# creamos un diccionario enumerando cada elemento
print({"elemento_{0}".format(i):e for i,e in enumerate(lista, 1)}) 
{'elemento_1': 1, 'elemento_2': 2, 'elemento_3': 3, 'elemento_4': 4, 'elemento_5': 5, 'elemento_6': 6, 'elemento_7': 7, 'elemento_8': 8, 'elemento_9': 9}
```

Volviendo a tu ejemplo:

```
langs = [language for language in languages if language['name'] == name]
```

La explicación es: se inicializa una nueva lista `langs` con los elementos de una lista de diccionarios `languajes` que cumplan con la condición que `name` == name. O sea básicamente estamos "filtrando" la lista original en una nueva.

Answer (score 0):

Es una funcionalidad llamada comprensión de listas, permite crear listas en una misma línea de código, esto se ve mucho mejor, por ejemplo, en la forma tradicional:

```
lista = []
for letra in 'casa':
    lista.append(letra)
print(lista)
```

**Resultado:** ['c', 'a', 's', 'a']

Con comprensión de listas:

```
lista = [letra for letra in 'casa']
print(lista)
```

**Resultado:** ['c', 'a', 's', 'a']

El código tradicional de tres líneas se redujo a una línea.